# Android building error - depends on undefined module

Tags: android, module, undefined

I am facing that problem. I synced all repo few times but didn't work :(

Output:

error: external/e2fsprogs/contrib/android/Android.bp:35:1: "ext2simg" depends on undefined module "libz-host" error: frameworks/base/media/jni/Android.bp:1:1: "libmedia_jni" depends on undefined module "libexif" error: frameworks/base/Android.bp:644:1: "ext" depends on undefined module "tagsoup" 
error: external/linux-kselftest/Android.bp:87:1: "kselftest_capabilities_test" depends on undefined module "libcap-ng"